# Table with orders and items in angularjs (master details table)

Tags: angularjs, html-table, master-detail

I'm an angularJS beginner and I'm struggling with master-details view.
I'm trying to achieve a table like this

```
<table>
<tbody ng-repeat="o in orders">
 <tr><td>{{o.ID}}</td></tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <!-- reusable subview - this should be in separate html file -->
    <table class="items">
     <tr><td>item 1</td></tr>
     <tr><td>item 2</td></tr>
     <tr><td>item 3</td></tr>
    </table>
   <!-- / -->
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What should I do to render the items sub-table for each order row?
In my index.html I've got a div with ng-view directive where my orders view renders but I can't get the items sub-view to work.

Comment: What you _should_ do is probably to read at least the official AngularJS tutorial (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial). Your question is very, very basic and even if we are able to help you it seems unlikely to me that you grasp the whole concept. You should read up about directives and scopes.

Comment: I think you didn't get what I'm trying to achieve here.
I read the tutorial and googled for couple of hours.
I want the items of each order listed below the order's row in the same view - no "click to see items".
the reason I want to do subview (or something like that) is because I want to reuse the items view someplace else.

Comment: "You should read up about directives and scopes." - great advice. thanks!